# Dependency Injection on a Composite (E4, RCP, SWT)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, swt, e4

I´m currently developing an E4 RCP Application and I have the following problem: 
I have an Part that isn´t visible at the opening of the application (toBeRendered="false" visible="false"). 
When a button klick on another Part happens, I do the following:

```
MPart s = partService.findPart("S");
if (s != null) {
s.setToBeRendered(true);
s.setVisible(true);
partService.activate(s); }
```

This works well. So if the user opens the Part (s) a Composite is created on that Part via a class and in this class I have dependency Injection:

```
public class S {
    ....
    @Focus
    public void focusGained() {
        ...
        MyComposite m = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        ...
    }
}



public class MyComposite extends Composite {

    @Named("list")
    private HashMap<String, Ex> myMap;

    public MyComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);
            myMap.get("key");
        }
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException at myMap.get("key"); so the Injection does not work. 
It works on another Part, that is created before this Composite is created so I don´t understand why this Injection does not work.

May someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection is only done on objects that the application model knows about. You are creating `MyComposite` yourself so injection is not done.

You can do the injection yourself with something like:

```
MyComposite m = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);

ContextInjectionFactory.inject(m, context);
```

Note: this will not do injection in the constructor, use a `@PostConstruct` method.

In any case field injection is not done until after the constructor has run, so your constructor code will never run with injection.

Update: You also only have `@Named` on the field, you need `@Inject` as well.

So your class needs to look like:

```
public class MyComposite extends Composite {

  @Named("list")
  @Inject
  private HashMap<String, Ex> myMap;

  public MyComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  void postConstruct() {
        myMap.get("key");
  }
}
```